# Mysql find names not in previous dates

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql database that contains  a list of names and dates of volunteers going back five years.  What statement would I use to generate a list of new names after a specific date (i.e. people that have not volunteered in the past).

Here is an example, I have a list of 100 different volunteers who have volunteered many times on different dates over 5 years to the present. Some may have volunteered once, others 5 times, etc. Dave is a new volunteer who volunteered on February 6, 2015. I wish to generate a list of new volunteers after 2014-11-29. This list would pick up Dave's name only in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT name
FROM your_table
WHERE column_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 YEAR);
```

Or:

```
SELECT name
FROM your_table
WHERE column_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 YEAR);
```

---

**EDIT (after the comments):**

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT aa.name
FROM your_table AS aa
WHERE aa.id NOT IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM your_table
    WHERE column_date < '2014-11-29'
);
```

Comment: I need something along the lines of   SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM your_table
WHERE column_date > 2014-11- 30 AND name does not appear prior to 2014-11-29.

Comment: Here is an example, I have a list of 100 different volunteers who have volunteered many times on different dates over 5 years to the present.  Some may have volunteered once, others 5 times, etc.  Dave is a new volunteer who volunteered on February 6, 2015.  I wish to generate a list of new volunteers after 2014-11-29.  This list would pick up Dave's name only in this instance.

Comment: Oh, do you mean you want the volunteers that they have volunteered only one time after a specific date?

Comment: They may have volunteered several times after the date.  The key is I am looking for new people who have not volunteered at any time prior to 2014-11-29.

Comment: Try the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, I do not have a user id number but substituting name for id worked.